# What exactly is a Unet?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Is every symmetrical fully convolutional network a Unet?

Does the skip connections between the downsampling path and the upsampling path always need to apply a concatenation operator instead of a sum? What difference does it make if we use sum?

Can I assume that if a network has unequal no. of upsampling and downsampling layers, it is an FCN and not a Unet?

Answer (score 1):

Every UNet is a FCN, but they can have extra techniques appended.

There isn't an "exact UNet", you can make lots of changes. 
In the last image segmentation competition I participated, everyone talked about modified UNets with customized decoder sides.

They can concatenate the connections, sum, multiply. There are even attention mechanisms to be used. A lot of people created UNets from ResNets, for instance.

The UNets are just nets that have two sides, down and upsampling, with connections between.